# Laravel 5 - try catch exception not working

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5, try-catch

I am new to laravel5 and this code fails to catch all the exceptions.
I don't know what's wrong, please help.

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $sql = $this->deleteSql();

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $deleteData = Db::delete($sql, ['id' => $id]);
        if (!$deleteData) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    DB::commit();
}
```

It will give me :

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22P02]:**
and 
**Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]:**

Answer (score -1):

Your method is not going to `catch` block at all since it is returning `bool` from `try` block.

Also I don't know what made you use `try...catch` block.

I more error:

```
Db::delete($sql, ['id' => $id]);
```

If you have defined `Db`, then it is okay. But if not, then it will throw error.

Also there is no need to use transactions, unless you are testing your application with any PHP Testing tool like phpUnit / phpSpec, etc.

---

**Solution:**

There is no need to use `try..catch` block at all.

Just call the delete method on the model that you wish to delete, and you will be done, like so:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    YourModel::delete($id); // Replace YourModel with the model you wish to delete

    \Session::flash('delete_message', 'Model has been successfully deleted.');

    return redirect()->back(); // or anywhere else of your choice
}
```

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding. Cheers.

Comment: thank you for your answer @user3514160. Actually i'm testing my application that's why I need it.

Comment: using what ?? phpUnit or any other testing tool ?

Comment: I tried to comment out the return bool if "Db::delete($sql, ['id' => $id]);" will have error, but still it will not catch the error. So is there a way to catch errors?

Comment: Then kindly update the question with whatever you are using and/or doing.. Don't just show the error message.. Where is the testing code ? the code that you wrote in testfile.php ? Also you have not said anything about testing in your question. Your code looks like that of controller and not of testing.. Kindly update the question.